# Scrolling BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, scroll, buffer, bufferedimage

I'm making a simple side scroller game in Java but am having trouble making the camera move with the person. My plan was to create a buffered image that could adjust the region of the image that is displaying and simply have it follow my character. However, I couldn't find any functions in the API to change the region of the buffered image that's displayed, so how could I do this? Thanks for any help provided.

```
 //The level is created in an 800x400 pixel size, is there any way I can change
 //the region myImage displays?
myImage =  new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well while you will be drawing your image you have a lot of options for example [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) function can draw any rectangle from your original image on any rectangle of the surface you get `Graphics` object from.

Comment: @user3050810 Well for example if you'll override `paint` or `paintComponent` method you will be getting `Graphics g` as it's argument, then you can call something like `g.drawImage (myImage, 0, 0, 400, 400, x, 0, x + 400, 400, null);` it will draw the rectangle `400x400` from `myImage` with offset `x` on component you've overridden method from. If you want to draw on some images just get `Graphics` with `createGraphics` function and so on.

Comment: Hey thanks, I got it all working. I really appreciate the help.